# Stop and return value of a recursive method in java

Tags: java, android, string, methods, recursion

I am trying to do a recursive method which returns a some random characters by some rules. The method works great, but the problem is that it doesn't return the value i need nor stop when i write `return myString`

here is the method(please take a look at comments):

```
 public String RowGenerator(String sir) {

    upper = "";

    Log.v(TAG, "RowGenerator Started");
    int randI = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 4);
    int randJ = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    int randK = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    Log.v(TAG, "inside RowGenerator: randI " + randI + ", randJ " + randJ + ", randK "+ randK);

    String upper = sir.replaceAll("[^A-Z]+", "");
    sir = sir.replaceAll("[^a-z]+", "");

    Log.v(TAG, "String upper " + upper);

//checking if there is a..z & sir>=5
    if ((sir.length()>=5) && upper.isEmpty()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "sir <5 & !b " + String.valueOf(sir));  // here it prints out exactly what i need, but when i setText id has another value.
        sir1.setText(String.valueOf(sir));  // this textview does not get the right value.
        return sir; // i want to end the function here and return the value , as i call it as follows: someString = String.valueOf(RowGenerator(sir))
    } else if (sir.isEmpty()) {
        sir = S[1];
        Log.v(TAG, "First sir value: " + sir);
        RowGenerator(sir);
    }  else if (sir.length()<5 && upper.isEmpty()) {
        sir = "";
        RowGenerator(sir);
    }
     // if there is A..Z
    else if (!upper.equals(null)) {
        if(upper.equals(S[0])) {
            sir = sir + S[1];
        } else if (upper.equals(I[0])) {
            sir = sir + I[randI];
        } else if (upper.equals(J[0])) {
            sir = sir + J[randJ];
        } else if (upper.equals(K[0])) {
            sir = sir + K[randK];
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "new value added to sir: " + sir);
        RowGenerator(sir);

    }
    Log.v(TAG, "returning value ");  // everything goes great till here, but then this log appears like 5-20 times randomly at each start, it should end in first if, but it got till here
    sir1.setText(String.valueOf(sir));
    return sir; 
}
```

as far as i know return `myString();` should stop the method and return the value, but it doesnt. please help me find what is wrong with my method.

any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: My gut feel is that you have massively overcomplicated your method. If you break it down it will be easier to debug. I guess  `if ((sir.length()>=5) && upper.isEmpty()) {` condition is never met

Comment: it is met, i just didn't post the imput S,I,J and K. in log i get that it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `RowGenerator(sir);` it does not return. It means the result is forgotten and the method processing continues.

As the final code block (containing the `Log` and `return sir;`) is not protected by an if it is executed every time, printing many logs. It also explains why the final result is incorrect (in these cases the method returns the value it received in parameter instead of recursing).

I guess you should replace `RowGenerator(sir);` by `return RowGenerator(sir);` to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Change `RowGenerator(sir);` statements to `return RowGenerator(sir);`.

Comment: there i need to call the method again, why would i return the value?

Comment: yes.. of course you are calling the method `RowGenerator(sir)`, you just need to return the method's return value...

Answer (score 0):

Actually in recursive methods the `return()` action returns the value to the previous function call.
 For example if the method has called itself 4 times and in the 4th time `return()` is called then the method in the 3rd level will continue from the line in which the 4th function call was executed and so on until the first function does the `return()`.
I don't know about your whole program but if this was all of your code a simple `system.exit(1)` would suffice.